# Custom JWT IN PHP keeps saying Invalid signature

Tags: php, jwt, token, signature

I am new to this and I am trying my best to create my own JWT class. I think I have done everything right, but when I try to paste my token in the jwt.io, it keeps saying signature invalid. I can't help but feel I am either missing something silly or something is wrong.

My code is below:

```
class Jwt
{
protected $header;

protected $payload;

protected $signature;

protected $secret;

protected $alg;

protected $jwt;

function __construct($header, $payload, $secret)
{
$this->SetHeader($header);
$this->alg = $header['alg'];
$this->SetPayload($payload);
$this->secret = $secret;
$this->SetSignature();
}

public function SetHeader($header){
$this->header = str_replace(["+", "/", "="],
['-', '_',""],
base64_encode(json_encode($header)));   
}

public function SetPayload($payload)
{
$this->payload = 
str_replace(["+", "/", "="],
['-',   '_',""],
base64_encode(json_encode($payload)));  
}

public function SetSignature()
{
$data = $this->header.".".$this->payload;
$this->alg = str_replace('HS', 'sha', $this->alg);
$hashedData = hash_hmac($this->alg, $data , $this->secret, true);
$this->signature = str_replace(
["+", "/", "="], ['-', '_', ""],   base64_encode($hashedData)
);
}

public function SetJwt()
{
$this->jwt = $this->header.'.'.$this->payload.'.'.$this->signature;
}

public function GetJwt()
{
return $this->jwt;
}
```

In my Index.php:

```
use root\lib\Jwt;
$myFavorites = 
['element' => 'Sun', 'animal' => 'Leopard','color'=>'Orange'];
$secret = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));

$jwt = new Jwt
(['alg' => 'HS256', 'typ' => 'JWT'], $myFavorites, $secret)
$jwt->SetJwt();

var_dump($jwt->GetJwt());
```

Everything works fine, the debugger shows the correct output but somehow it just says invalid signature.

If I change the algorithm on the jwt.io website it works. So I'm guessing its something to do with the signature or the algorithms

I am copying it from the output on the screen from the var_dump, could this be the reason why?

New token is: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbGVtZW50IjoiU3VuIiwiYW5pbWFsIjoiTGVvcGFyZCIsImNvbG91ciI6Im9yYW5nZSJ9.LF-4HNxgzhqYaIQKTImwO8A8SHIZfVYz2iG57A4tQm0

I even tried changing the algorithm in the header th HS256 or HS384 and then hard coding the change inside the function, it made no difference

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Try base64UrlEncoding: `function base64url_encode($data) { return rtrim( strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');}`

Comment: I tried it, the result is the same, its very strange

Comment: Once I put it in the debugger and then change the algorithm there and then go back to the same algorithm it works, but JWT creates its own new signature for it

Comment: the token looks basically ok, only the alg header is wrong. Did you also paste the secret into the secret field under `verify signature`of the jwt.io debugger?

Comment: Now I think it worked :), Hoping its not too good to be true, Im going to try again with a different number. Do you think the secret should be generated with a random number?

Comment: So, the missing secret on jwt.io was the last problem? You can use a long random string, avoid using words or sentences.

Comment: But something's not right about that, it now says secret verified, but it allows me to put any random secret in it and it still works, Is this normal?

Comment: the debugger recalculates the hash when you change the secret, therefore you always paste your secret intothe field first and then paste your token on the left side.

Comment: Hey when I do this, it definitely works, after that, if I remove the secret, it still says valid but just adjusts the token and no matter what secret I put, it still says its valid but it adjusts the token. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes of course, Just one last doubt, from my previous comment, if you could give me some reassurance that its fine, that would be great :)

Comment: yes, as I said above, jwt.io always recalculates the hash. When you remove your secret, then it's hasing with an emtpy string as secret. But that doesn't matter for you, important is, that you validated your token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're using HMAC hashing which takes the algorithm parameter `sha256` or `sha384`. These algorithm names are not identical to the algorithm names that can be used in a JWT.

In [RFC 7517 section 4.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.1)
you can read about the `alg` header:

> A list of defined "alg" values for this use can be found in the IANA
> "JSON Web Signature and Encryption Algorithms" registry established
> by [JWA]; the initial contents of this registry are the values
> defined in Section 3.1 of [JWA].

According to [RFC7518 section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.1) for HMAC ShaXXX algorithms, you have you use `HSXXX`, e.g `HS256` or `HS384`

The [JWT.io](https://jwt.io) debugger or any other software that tries to verify the JWT reads this header and then tries with the algortihm. If you use a non standard name, the verifying software can't find the right algortihm.

A note regarding the use of [JWT.io](https://jwt.io): don't forget to paste the secret into the input field under `Verify Signature` in the right column of the debugger, **before** you paste the token into the left column. If you forget the secret, the token can't be verifyed and if you paste the secret after the token, the signature might get recalculated and changed on the left side.

Comment: I did try that and tried once again, the same thing happens. I will post the updated code. So basically I use HS256 in the header, do I just hard code sha256 for the HMAC hashing? Or is there another way?

Comment: I believe it now works jps, I think I tried it before, but it works, and thank you for highlighting the alg difference, now it works, Im basically doing a str_replace from HS to SHA, saves me from hard coding it